# Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: typescript, dom-events

When trying to access the dataset on a button after a click, I get this^ error.

```
linkProvider = (ev: React.SyntheticEvent<EventTarget>) => {
  console.debug('ev.target', ev.target.dataset['ix']) // error
}

// in render 
providers.map((provider, ix) => (
  <button key={provider} data-ix={ix} onClick={this.linkProvider}>{provider}</button>
))
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Problem is here `Element`, `document`, and `window` can be an [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget). You should detect your `EventTarget` if is an element. So in your case below code should work

```
linkProvider = (ev: React.SyntheticEvent<EventTarget>) => {
  // If event target not an HTMLButtonElement, exit
  if (!(ev.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement)) {
    return;
  }
  console.debug('ev.target', ev.target.dataset['ix']) 
}
```

In the short way

```
linkProvider = (ev: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  console.debug('ev.target', ev.currentTarget.dataset['ix']) 
}
```

And also i added example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-9bsqye)

Comment: This is little more verbose. Why doesn't this `React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>` work?

Comment: You can access it through `e.currentTarget.dataset.pageNumber` pageNumber as an example here

Answer (score 4):

Combining both suggestions provided by @Efe and @fatemefazli, I came to a solution that works:

[image]

For reference, this is the interface and the reason why it doesn't work with `target`: ([github link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L1204))

```
interface SyntheticEvent<T> {
    /**
     * A reference to the element on which the event listener is registered.
     */
    currentTarget: EventTarget & T;

    // If you thought this should be `EventTarget & T`, see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/12239
    /**
     * A reference to the element from which the event was originally dispatched.
     * This might be a child element to the element on which the event listener is registered.
     *
     * @see currentTarget
     */
    target: EventTarget;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with this shorter solution to show both of answers

Comment: The problem here is that `target` is not always equal to `currentTarget`

Comment: This does not solve the problem in case of Event Delegation pattern because dataset is on child element, but event handler is attached to parent element. I guess React types should be fixed. Simple example: `<ul onClick={({ target: { dataset: { value } } }: MouseEvent<HTMLUListElement> & { target: { dataset: { value?: string } }; }) => { console.debug(value); }} ><li data-value="foo">item 1</li><li data-value="bar">item 2</li></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

If I may try to add to [Efe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9034168/efe)'s response:

I think it makes sense also to check that the property `dataset` has the `ix` attribute before you use the attribute*:

```
linkProvider = (ev: React.SyntheticEvent<EventTarget>) => {
  if (!(ev.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement)) {
    return;
  }

  if (ev.target.dataset.ix) {
    /// event handler logic
  }

  
}
```

**got that example from a front-end-masters course*